# Simple chat application with canned answers

Tags: chat

I am setting up a remote event and I am looking for a solution so that the remote person can communicate with me as they cannot talk or type text.

The person at the other end can touch prompts on a screen or type single letter words but they are busy playing piano, so typing whole sentences is impossible. I need to communicate with that person to make sure that everything is fine. I can talk to them with voice, but I would like them to be able to answer questions like "do you hear me" or acknowledge messages like "end of show in 30 seconds".

Ideally, the application would be simply web-based, and it would let me type baked answers and just show them on the other person's screen for them to choose.